# Rav Moshe milk and tuna

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, fish, moshe-feinstein, non-kosher-species

Rav Moshe holds that tuna needs a masgiach timidi for it to be consumed,every fish needs to be checked for the simanim.However, by milk he brings a savarah that the government is sufficient and a mashgiach timidi is not needed and one can technically drink such milk.

what is the difference by fish why can't we say the same savarah like milk,I believe Rav Ahron Kotler used such a savarah.

Comment: Also: the government doesn't check (or have a fine) for simanim. They do check (and fine) for milk.

Comment: @yydl They don't check and fine to ensure that every fish in a can of tuna is a tuna?

Comment: @DoubleAA, re your last comment: I can't say with any certainty, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/21/us/survey-finds-that-fish-are-often-not-what-label-says.html

Comment: @DoubleAA From what I heard they do have a government inspector there but he's liable to miss a few. Plus milk is just so much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rabbi J. David Bleich quotes R. Moshe on this question as follows ("SURVEY OF RECENT HALAKHIC PERIODICAL LITERATURE," *Tradition* 18:4):

> Rabbi Feinstein addresses himself specifically to the question of
>   government supervision and to the contention that fear of punitive
>   measures may constitute an adequate substitute for the presence of a
>   mashgiach. Rabbi Feinstein peremptorily dismisses the notion that
>   government inspection might constitute an adequate safeguard.
>   Moreover, he argues, even a mashgiach "exiting and entering" (i.e.,
>   a mashgiach who comes and goes periodically but who is not constantly present) is not sufficient. Such supervision is satisfactory, declares Rabbi Feinstein, only if the activity under supervision is one of sufficient duration so that the mashgiach, on his return, might be able to apprehend a malfactor in the midst of the act. Removal of the skin of a fish, however, can be accomplished so swiftly that a person who wishes to substitute a nonkosher fish need not fear that the kashrut supervisor might return and catch him in the act. Therefore, rules Rabbi Feinstein, it is necessary for the mashgiach to be present constantly throughout the canning process and for him to examine each fish.